# Read and write datas with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a access with a excel vba macro to look after some data in a .mdb database and write it into the workbook to work with it.

I took a example whih I have found in google but I'm getting a error at the SELECT line. I tried it also with selecting all datas in the db with just `rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Tabelle1"` but I'm still getting an

> "Run-time error '3709' The connection cannot be used to perform this
> operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context."

Can someone help me ?

kind regards

```
Sub DatenLesen()

Dim strDB As String
Dim strTab As String
Dim objcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Zeile As Long

strDB = "C:\Daten.mdb"
strTab = "Daten"
Testuser = "TestUser"

Set objcon = New ADODB.Connection
'Verbindung zur Datenbank wird aufgenommen
objcon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strDB

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Tabelle1 WHERE VK=" & Testuser
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Tabelle1"
    
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
   
   MsgBox "OK"
   'Do Until rst.EOF
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.AddItem rst!Kürzel
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(1, Zeile) = rst!patname
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(2, Zeile) = rst!patvorname
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(3, Zeile) = rst!Leistung
   '  If rst!km <> "" Then
   '   frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(4, Zeile) = rst!km
   '  End If
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(5, Zeile) = rst!Datum
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(6, Zeile) = rst!Uhrzeit
   '  frm_Daten.ListBox1.Column(7, Zeile) = rst!ID
   '  Zeile = Zeile + 1
   '  frm_Daten.ProgressBar1.Value = Zeile
   ' rst.MoveNext
   'Loop
   
  Else
   MsgBox "Nichts gefunden"
  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You need the connection `rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Tabelle1", objcon`

Comment: I highly recommend learning Power Query for this. Maybe not this time because you're sooooo close! But you can probably do this with very little typing if you start with the "Get & Transform" section of the data ribbon in Excel and go from there. It will build your table for you and then you can massage it from there.

Comment: @CDP1802 that helped. I tried now the command `Sheets("DB").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst` and that worked too but when i bind this sub to a button and press several times to update the datas in the worksheet, it starts copying the datas incorrectly at the 2nd or 3rd time. And once it started ready the datas incorrectly it doesn't fix it by itself.

Comment: @fre4k You really need to show the code you have, but try a `rst.MoveFirst` before the `.CopyFromRecordset`.